# Microsoft Graph API - Admin GrantApplication Permissions

Tags: api, graph, permissions, azure-ad-graph-api

On this page
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

It says

"You can rely on an administrator to grant the permissions your app needs at the Azure portal;"

I don't see any documentation/instructions on where or how this can be done.

The goal is for the graph api to run without signing in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this documentation:
[Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#updating-an-application)

> As an administrator, you can also consent to an application's
>   delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant.
>   Administrative consent prevents the consent dialog from appearing for
>   every user in the tenant, and is done your application page in the
>   Azure portal. From the Settings page for your application, click
>   Required Permissions and click on the Grant Permissions button.

[image]

Comment: This grants permission for a azure ad api. based on a convo with a microsoft rep, it is scheduled for deprecation (I don't remember when). this question is for the microsoft graph api, it's replacement.

Comment: The grant permissions button will work for any API that you selected in the "Require Permissions" menu. This includes the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: The ui you have there is if you create api apps in this portal, https://portal.azure.com,  these are the azure ad 1.0 apis. The new 2.0 api does not show up in the ui you display here and they are created in a different portal that shows both versions of apis but has abilities to manage 1.0 api, https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

I missed step 3 (Get administrator consent). This is the part that allows you to run the api as an application/service. Your Azrue AD user needs to be an admin. After this you can bypass the authorization code that you normally go through.